# Variance split interpretation in factor analysis

Tags: machine-learning, factor-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a quick question on PCA and Factor Analysis.

One of the benefits of FA over PCA as I understood (correct me if wrong) is a more comprehensive model of the variance in the original data as split in common variance, unique variance and error variance but I am struggling to see how error variance is modelled.

Let me explain with an equation. Assume my data points are stored in matrix X. When I perform factors analysis the following decomposition is estimated:

[image: equation]

QUESTION: 
If we assume the original data has been standardised to zero mean to ignore mu (not relevant here), am I right in assuming common variance is modelled by the common factors term  [image: equation] while unique variance is modelled by  [image: equation]? If so, is the error variance modelled within [image: equation] as well?

Thanks a lot for your help and hope my question makes sense.

Comment: you should try to only ask one question per thread